# Transferring pointer addresses from 2-dimensional array to structure

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, struct

this is my first input here, so I am sorry for any aspects not going along with the rules.

I have to connect two applications by a C++ interface. Application A stores the values to be exchanged in the 2-dimensional dynamic array double** Parameters. Application A calls the function:

```
void __cdecl function(double** Parameters)
```

Application B shall store the values of application A in a structure that is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct {
  double Input1;
  int Input2;
} Inputs;           // struct for input variables

typedef struct {
  double Output1;
  int Output2;
} Outputs;          //struct for output variables
```

The aim is to call another function with the arguments out and in that is written in application B. But first I want to connect Output1 and Input1 by a small calculation. So I define:

```
Double result;
Inputs in;      // name of a struct of type inputs
Outputs *out;   //name of the pointer for a struct of the type outputs

in.Input1[0] = *Parameters[0];      //value from Parameters[0] is put on in.Input[0]
out->Output1 = Parameters[1];       //pointer out shall store the address that is stored in Parameters[1]
result = 2 / in.Input1[0];      //calculate result
*(out)->Output1 = result;       //store the address of the value of result in the pointer out
```

I get an error message that says. “A value of type ""double *"" cannot be assigned to an entity of ""double"". So there must be something wrong with the exchange of the pointers. I have two questions so far:

1. How can I achieve that an address of the 2-dimensional dynamic array Parameters is stored in the structure pointer out?
2. How can I achieve that the the pointer out stores the address of the newly calculated value of result?

Thank you and Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

Following the definition of your struct `Inputs`:

```
typedef struct {
  double Input1;
  int Input2;
} Inputs;
```

And given the definition for `Parameters` as

```
double** Parameters;
```

Saying

```
in.Input1[0] = *Parameters[0];
```

Is not well formed, because `Input1` is a `double`, which you cannot index into. What you are trying to do is store an address at `Input1` which would not be safe, but if you want to attempt it, you can try type-punning (see my edit).

There are similar issues with

```
out->Output1 = Parameters[1]; // Output1 is a double, Parameters[1] is a double*
```

and

```
result = 2 / in.Input1[0]; //Input1 is a double, cannot index into it
```

---

#### EDIT

So you want to store the address of a double inside another double, and then later de-reference that address? This is not a safe thing to do, but if you absolutely must perform such a work-around, here's how you can pun a `double*` as a `double`, using a `union` trick:

Start by declaring a union that can hold a `double*` and a `double`:

```
// Warning, this is not recommended
union doubleToPtr{
    double* ptr;
    double dbl;
};
```

Now we can put a pointer in, and then get the `double` out, or vice-versa.

First let us store a pointer as a double:

```
// seriously, don't do this unless you're forced to
double parameter = 4.0;
double holdingAddress;
double toAssignTo;

// first pun the address of a double into a double
// by assigning to ptr in union, then reading out as double
doubleToPtr typePunnerIn;
typePunnerIn.ptr = &parameter;
holdingAddress = typePunnerIn.dbl;
```

Next, on the other side we can use another union to take in a `double` (that we know is really an address), and then interpret it as a `double*`:

```
// third warning, ask yourself if you really need this
// next pun the double into a double address
// by assigning double into union
// then read out as address
doubleToPtr typePunnerOut;
typePunnerOut.dbl = holdingAddress;
toAssignTo = *(typePunnerOut.ptr);
```

And then we can print out `toAssignTo` and see that we have proceeded successfully:

```
std::cout << toAssignTo << std::endl;
```

> 4

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/554c240b0e26cd1e)

Answer (score 0):

thanks very much for your quick and detailed answer. It hepled me a lot to figure out where I want to go to.

I found a way withot that dangerous type punning. The structs are defined in another .h file:

```
 typedef struct {
  double Input1;
  int Input2;
} Inputs;           // struct for input variables

typedef struct {
  double Output1;
  int Output2;
} Outputs;          //struct for output variables
```

The main function looks like this now:

```
void __cdecl function(double** Parameters)
{   Inputs in1, *in;        //Define variable and pointer of Inputs 
    Outputs out1, *out;     //Define variable and pointer of Outputs
    double result;

    in = &in1;     //get the adress of the struct in1
    out = &out1;   //get the adress of the struct out1

    in1.Input1 = *dParameters[0];   //get the first value from the Array dParameters
    result = 2 / in.Input1          //calculate result

    *(dParameters[1]) = out1.Output1;   //rewrite value in the address on which the pointer dParameters[1] is pointing
}
```

I hope I explained it properly. Another question: I found two ways of defining a pointer on a structure

```
struct Inputs *ptr;   //or
Inputs *ptr;
```

Can you say what is the difference?

Thank you